# в .tsx файле ошибка на импорте других .tsx файлов

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

Делаю проект через Webpack с использованием React и TypeScript. У меня есть main.tsx файл:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

import App from './App.tsx';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Но есть проблема, при открытии файла main.tsx у меня подчёркивает красным строку с импортом App и выдаёт это: "**An import path can only end with a '.tsx' extension when 'allowImportingTsExtensions' is enabled.ts(5097)**", при этом проект запускается и работает нормально, хоть и показывает 1 ошибку. Когда я закрываю файл, ошибка пропадает, и соответственно появляется при открытии.

Как решить эту проблему, чтобы оно не жаловалось на импорт?

P.S: Кому нужно, вот мой webpack.config.js:

```
/**
 * Webpack main configuration file
 */

const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require("image-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const environment = require("./configuration/environment");

const templateFiles = fs
  .readdirSync(environment.paths.source)
  .filter((file) =>
    [".html", ".ejs"].includes(path.extname(file).toLowerCase())
  )
  .map((filename) => ({
    input: filename,
    output: filename.replace(/\.ejs$/, ".html"),
  }));

const htmlPluginEntries = templateFiles.map(
  (template) =>
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      hash: false,
      filename: template.output,
      template: path.resolve(environment.paths.source, template.input),
      favicon: path.resolve(
        environment.paths.source,
        "assets",
        "images",
        "favicon.ico"
      ),
    })
);

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    pp: path.resolve(environment.paths.source, "main.tsx"),
  },
  output: {
    filename: "js/[name].js",
    path: environment.paths.output,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.((c|sa|sc)ss)$/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|tsx|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|gif|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        type: "asset",
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: environment.limits.images,
          },
        },
        generator: {
          filename: "images/design/[name].[hash:6][ext]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        type: "asset",
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: environment.limits.images,
          },
        },
        generator: {
          filename: "fonts/[name].[hash:6][ext]",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      "...",
      new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
        minimizer: {
          implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.imageminMinify,
          options: {
            // Lossless optimization with custom option
            // Feel free to experiment with options for better result for you
            plugins: [
              ["gifsicle", { interlaced: true }],
              ["jpegtran", { progressive: true }],
              ["optipng", { optimizationLevel: 5 }],
              // Svgo configuration here https://github.com/svg/svgo#configuration
              [
                "svgo",
                {
                  plugins: [
                    {
                      name: "removeViewBox",
                      active: false,
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            ],
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "css/[name].css",
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      verbose: true,
      cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ["**/*", "!stats.json"],
    }),
  ].concat(htmlPluginEntries),
  target: "web",
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
};
```

Comment: Да никто не указывает это в импорте. Без .tsx попробуйте

Comment: Проблему решил, через создание react-app-env.in.ts с указанием внутри "/// <reference types="react-scripts" />"

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка сама говорит о проблеме. Импортировать файл с написанием `.tsx` можно только если в `tsconfig.json` стоит `allowImportingTsExtensions: true`.

Либо добавьте `allowImportingTsExtensions: true` в `tsconfig.json`, либо импортируйте без расширения `.tsx`